# Failed to compile. ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages.js Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Getting the below error in React app,

> Failed to compile. ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'E:\project\ruchkarsolapurwbt\frontend\pwa\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modules@babel\runtime/helpers/slicedToArray' 
>   in 'E:\project\ruchkarsolapurwbt\frontend\pwa\node_modules\react-dev-utils'

Please help me to resolve it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember that this is not a general help forum; read the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article and then please update your post accordingly. Without any mention of what you already tried/looked at, and what you already searched the web for but didn't work, there are far too many reasons this might happen, necessitating a support chat, rather than the post based question/answer approach that Stackoverflow is for.

Comment: I tried this commands before posting the prblem.
git clean -d -f
git reset --hard
but not worked fir me.

then 
npm add @babel runtime 
worked for me.

Comment: That sounds like doing things entirely wrong. You should only need a _single_ command, namely `npx create-react-app my-app`. Running that with the most recent versions of Node will do exactly what it needs to do. So: did you run that command, or did you install things yourself, in a completely different way?

Comment: I run that command

Comment: Then you should really add a bit more detail: which OS, which version of node, the exact command you ran, and probably the full log of your install run. However, you should also probably _not_ ask that here, but ask that over on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues first, because they are the first place you should check, before you start posting on more general websites.

Answer (score 18):

I have the same issue, I resolved my deleting my node_modules folder and running npm install again.

Comment: The above answer resolved the exact same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. Try to fix the issue by running:

```
npm add @babel/runtime
```

and then:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with pnpm. Build worked locally but was failing on Netlify with:

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+runtime@7.18.9/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/slicedToArray.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

I have solved it by adding in `.npmrc` :

```
hoist-pattern[]=@babel/runtime
```

and adding `@babel/runtime` to production dependencies (no -D flag!)

```
pnpm add @babel/runtime
```